# Fatal Error in Ruby on Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi we had an app copied over to a new domain and are getting the following errors in the log.  Can anyone point us in the right direction since we are no experts in Ruby on Rails?

```
F, [2018-04-17T07:01:04.366958 #32309] FATAL -- : [e1fdedc8-ccf2-4537-a2ca-2760fd71eb68]   
F, [2018-04-17T07:01:04.367095 #32309] FATAL -- : [e1fdedc8-ccf2-4537-a2ca-2760fd71eb68] ActionView::Template::Error (Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true):
F, [2018-04-17T07:01:04.367316 #32309] FATAL -- : [e1fdedc8-ccf2-4537-a2ca-2760fd71eb68]     87:                 </tr>
[e1fdedc8-ccf2-4537-a2ca-2760fd71eb68]     88:                 <tr style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; margin: 0;">  <td class="content-block" style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: top; margin: 0; padding: 0 0 20px;" valign="top">
[e1fdedc8-ccf2-4537-a2ca-2760fd71eb68]     89:                     <p>
[e1fdedc8-ccf2-4537-a2ca-2760fd71eb68]     90:                       <a href="<%= lead_url(@lead, host: ENV['root_url'] ) %>"> <%= @lead.address %></p>
[e1fdedc8-ccf2-4537-a2ca-2760fd71eb68]     91:                   </td>
[e1fdedc8-ccf2-4537-a2ca-2760fd71eb68]     92:                 </tr>
[e1fdedc8-ccf2-4537-a2ca-2760fd71eb68]     93:                 <tr style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; margin: 0;"><td class="content-block" style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: top; margin: 0; padding: 0 0 20px;" valign="top">
F, [2018-04-17T07:01:04.367370 #32309] FATAL -- : [e1fdedc8-ccf2-4537-a2ca-2760fd71eb68]   
F, [2018-04-17T07:01:04.367412 #32309] FATAL -- : [e1fdedc8-ccf2-4537-a2ca-2760fd71eb68] app/views/offer_mailer/lead_received_email.html.erb:90:in `_app_views_offer_mailer_lead_received_email_html_erb__2123924889929648841_69874930248760'
[e1fdedc8-ccf2-4537-a2ca-2760fd71eb68] app/mailers/offer_mailer.rb:6:in `lead_received_email'
[e1fdedc8-ccf2-4537-a2ca-2760fd71eb68] app/controllers/wizards_controller.rb:79:in `email_notify_agent'
[e1fdedc8-ccf2-4537-a2ca-2760fd71eb68] app/controllers/wizards_controller.rb:54:in `notify_agent'
[e1fdedc8-ccf2-4537-a2ca-2760fd71eb68] app/controllers/wizards_controller.rb:31:in `validate_step'
```

Comment: Is seems that your `ENV['root_url']` is not set which is causing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to the `config/environment.rb` file adding below line

```
Rails.application.routes.default_url_options = { :host => "https://example.herokuapp.com" } 
#=> host you can change your domain
```

you can use this separately in `development.rb`, `production.rb` and `test.rb`

**production.rb**

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "https://example.herokuapp.com" }
```

make sure restart the server after making changes

**Update**

Now I think the issue raising for `ENV['root_url']`, can you change this like below

```
<%= lead_url(@lead, host: 'https://your-domain.com' ) %>
```

for test purpose and see what's happening, if it's working then you can set up the environment variable in the right way

**For environment variable** you can use [`Figaro`](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) gem, add Figaro to your `Gemfile` and bundle install:

```
gem "figaro"
```

Figaro installation is easy:

```
bundle exec figaro install
#=> create  config/application.yml
```

after installing this go to `config/application.yml` and add URL like this

```
root_url: "https://you-domain.com"
```

then now

```
<%= ENV['root_url'] %>
#=> https://you-domain.com
```

Comment: is there any specific area in the environment.rb file I need to add that line or will anywhere do?

Comment: After this `Rails.application.initialize!` line

Comment: OK, then check your `production.rb`  and set `config.action_mailer.default_url_options`

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm still getting the same exact error.  I made sure to restart the server.  I appreciate your help!

Comment: does it matter where to place that line in production.rb?

Comment: No, that's does not matter, now I think the issue raised on `ENV['root_url']`, can you change this with `<%= lead_url(@lead, host: 'https://your-domain.com' ) %>` for test purpose and see what's happening

Comment: that solved that issue, but now we have a new error related to the postmark API.  What we are noticing is that anything that has ENV['various_values_here'] we are needing to hardcode fixes in.

Comment: OK, see the updated answer **For environment variable**

Comment: Thank you so much!  That took care of it and points me in the right direction for the other errors!  I gave it a +1 but it says it was recored but not publicly shown.

Comment: One more question... is there anything I have to do after updating the application.yml file?

Comment: If you push to your private repository then you can update your `.gitignore` file for pushing this `application.yml` it depends on you what do you want if you want to push this `application.yml` file  then comment `/config/application.yml` this line to your `.gitignore` otherwise, leave this